# How to retrieve only date and time data from TIME STAMP format field

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, timestamp

We are storing data of some text fields which is of type **TIME STAMP** in **DATABASE** when we are retrieving it is showing only date and time as we are using **@TEMPORAL** annotation for that POJO Class.

But now there is one requirement that we must retrieve **TIME STAMP** data with out **@TEMPORAL**  annotation what's happening now, it is retrieving complete data of that field in **TIME STAMP** format.

Which is not required for us we need only date and time from that **TIME STAMP** format. How to exclude other data by considering only date and time from that format. So guys please help me out with some valuable suggestions from your side.

I want to split that entire **TIME STAMP** data in to date and time in a java program.

Comment: Show input, expected output please. And what you have tried too.

Comment: What is the TIME STAMP format you receive?

Answer (score 0):

```
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm").format(myTimestamp);
```

or

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```